# How to differentiate between multiple node.exe

Tags: node.js, taskmanager

I am running a node.js application in which a parent process created a lot of child processes. In the task manager, there are multiple node.exe and I am not able to distinguish which node.exe is for which child process.
How can I distinguish between them?